# Validation in laravel 5.1

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

as would do this in laravel ?
I need to pass this condition laravel

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM citas WHERE
    especialidad='".$especialidad."'AND doctor='".$doctor."'AND
    fecha ='".$fecha."' AND hora = '".$hora."'" , $con);

if ($existe = mysql_fetch_object($query)) 
{

}else{}
```

**this is my table in the database:**

fecha          |       hora     | especialidad    |     doctor  |

12-07-2015 |    01:17:00 |  General          |   Carlos    |
12-07-2015 |    01:35:00 |  General          |   Carlos    |

**This would be what shipping.**

fecha          |       hora     | especialidad    |     doctor  |

12-07-2015 |    **01:22:00** |  General          |   Carlos    |  <--- It is saved by the time it is different 
12-07-2015 |    01:35:00 |  General          |   **uriel**       |  <---  It is saved by the dcotor it is different

12-07-2015 |    01:35:00 |  General          |   **carlos**       |  <---  It is no, because 
it already exists

Comment: Could you describe your question some more detailed?

Comment: I really hope you _don’t_ use raw variable values in SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = DB::table('citas')
    ->where('especialidad',$especialidad)
    ->where('doctor',$doctor)
    ->where('fecha',$fecha)
    ->where('hora',$hora)
    ->get();

if($query != null){
    // your code will be here
}else{
    // you code will be here
}
```

Or you can try this by `Eloquent Model`. I assume you have a model named `Cita`

Add `use App\Cita` at top of your code after `namespace` in your `controller`

```
$query = Cita::where('especialidad',$especialidad)
    ->where('doctor',$doctor)
    ->where('fecha',$fecha)
    ->where('hora',$hora)
    ->get();

if($query != null){
    // your code will be here
}else{
    // you code will be here
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering!. 
but it does not work me ,if you need 4 elements that no longer exist shipping store , but if one is different , so if you save it.

Comment: Do you want to match all 4 elements or any one element?

Comment: I didn't get you? Actually what are you trying to do?

Comment: is a medical book , so I want to make sure that there is no appointment for that day . , at that time , with that doctor and the specialty